# Not understand this recursive function that inverts digits of a number

Tags: c

I found this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int rev(int num)
{
    if(num < 10)
        return num;
    else
        return (num % 10) * pow(10, (int)log10(num)) + rev(num/10);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", rev(12345));

    return 0;
}
```

And I set out to analyzing it, but now I have one doubt it is the following, to return to the starting point what values are obtained with *(num % 10)* according to my understanding should be (1,2,3,4,5) but when trying do the calculation manually I do not get the expected value.

What happens here, if someone explains to me this, or I missed out something?

Comment: What is an "investor digit"?

Comment: It should be the opposite order, no?  rev(12345) = 50000 + rev(1234) = 54000 + rev(123) = ... = 54321.

Comment: Please post the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: Note: values like `1234567899` will not reverse properly as `9987654321` is likely outside `int` range.

Comment: @QuestionC I get the correct output, I just want to know that values is taking with (num % 10)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int rev(int num) // num = 12345
{
    if(num < 10) // false
        return num;
    else
        return (num % 10) * pow(10, (int)log10(num)) + rev(num/10);
        //     (12345 % 10) * 10 ^ (log 12345) + rev(12345/10);
        //     5 * 10 ^ (4) + rev (1234)
        //     50000 + rev(1234)
}
```

Based on this, we can assume that:

```
rev(12345) = 50000 + rev(1234)
rev(1234) = 4000 + rev(123)
rev(123) = 300 + rev(12)
rev(12) = 20 + rev(1)
rev(1) = 1
```

So, the end result is:

```
rev(12345) = 50000 + 4000 + 300 + 20 + 1 = 54321
```

It is a simple math, the only non trivial rule is `(int)log10(num)`, but it was explained by @QuestionC in his comment.

Comment: this confuses me more

Comment: It helps to note that `log10(x)` returns a floating point value in the form `A.B` where `A` is the number of digits in `x`.  So `(int)log10(num)` is the number of digits in `num`.  That's just a mathematical property of base 10 logarithms.

Comment: Er, it returns 1 less than the number of digits.